# How to insert multiple rows of data using both SELECT and VALUES in SQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

I have two tables, one is Owner and one is Pet, and Owner holds OwnerID auto-incremented integers. I need to select that OwnerID into my Pet table, as well as include distinct values for each pet name/birthday.

I tried this, but it just copied the same pet name/birthday for every row.

```
INSERT INTO  Pet (OwnerID, PetName, DateOfBirth)
SELECT OwnerID, 'Luna', '2013-08-26T12:00:00+00:00'
FROM Owner;
```

I've also tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Pet (OwnerID, PetName, DateOfBirth)
VALUES (
(SELECT OwnerID, 'Luna', 2013-02-11 FROM Owner), 
(SELECT OwnerID, 'Wally', 2014-09-28 FROM Owner), 
(SELECT OwnerID, 'Bella', 2019-07-04 FROM Owner), 
(SELECT OwnerID, 'Milo', 2017-03-15 FROM Owner));
```

But then the column count doesn't match the value at row 1.

So how can I both select the OwnerID and create unique PetName values for every row?

Comment: You want a different pet name for each owner?

Comment: Those selects all pull back the entire owners table.You would need a where clause on those selects for this to even make sense. How would it know which pet goes with which owner?

Comment: @JohnFx If I list the values individually, how do I select the OwnerID from the Owner table?

Comment: @Kevin Exactly! Each OwnerID has its own unique Pet Name

Comment: Provide `CREATE TABLE` scripts for both tables, `INSERT INTO` script for the data already present in `Owner`, and example data array which must be inserted into `Pet`. Do not forget to explain where the info about what Owner is an owner for each definite pet.

Comment: Could you post the specifications of both tables (e. g., the "create table ..." commands you used to create them) and explain what your general goal is? Is it that you want to (randomly) match potential owners with pets? Or is there already some information about how owners and pets are connected and you want to retrieve the owner id for the owner name or so? Or maybe something totally different?

Comment: @Avra Saslow Your current select statements won't match pets to an owner either. (if the syntax wasn't wrong) it would just map a random owner to a random pet. What in your DB schema identifies the link between pets and owners?

Comment: @David I just updated the post. I just want to insert info into the tables! I know it should be really simple but I'm just struggling haha. I want to insert maybe 6 rows of data for the Owner Name, Pet Name, and Birthday. But between auto-incrementing my PetID and OwnerID, it has gotten complicated.

Comment: It will not work because you have to specify which Owner/OwnerID do you want to use. Select OwnerID... selects all owner IDs in the table and then you add just one name for the pet. How should SQL know what to do`?

Comment: Well... you type `.. (SELECT OwnerID, 'Luna', 2013-02-11 FROM Owner), ..`. For example, there is 5 owner records in `Owner` table - how to determine what record from this 5 possible ones must be used in a record for the pet Luna?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you only want to insert data into the table?

Then you must specify which Owner goes with each pet, and it is as simple as

```
INSERT INTO Pet (OwnerID, PetName, DateOfBirth)
VALUES (1, 'Luna', '2013-02-11'), 
(4, 'Wally', '2014-09-28'), 
(6, 'Bella', '2019-07-04'), 
(12, 'Milo', '2017-03-15');
```

Owners must exist prior to that of course.

Comment: First add the owners by something like `INSERT INTO Owner(OwnerName) VALUES ('John Doe'), ('Joanne Doe);`. This will trigger the auto increment. You can then manually read the owner ids from the owner table, or use something like `INSERT INTO Pet (OwnerID, PetName, DateOfBirth)
VALUES ((SELECT OwnerID FROM Owner WHERE OwnerName = 'John Doe'), 'Luna', '2013-02-11'), (SELECT OwnerID FROM Owner WHERE OwnerName = 'Joanne Doe'), 'Wally', '2014-09-28');` - which will only work if there are no duplicate names in the owner table.